# window.location malfunctions when triggering a jQuery click programmatically

Tags: jquery, events, redirect, triggers, window.location

Consider this HTML

```
<table id="search_results">
    <tr><td><a href="reports.php" style="display:none">_</a>Report 1</td></tr>
</table>
```

I have written code that upon a mouse click on a TD whose parent (TR) contains an A tag with an href attribute, the window is redirected to that page:

```
//Set row clicking
$('table#search_results td').click(function () {
    var href = $(this).parent().find('a').attr("href");
    if (href) { window.location = href; }
});
```

This code works perfectly when it is the user that clicks the TD.  However I have written code that triggers the click event when the return button is pressed.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        $('table#search_results tr:not([class=vanish]) td:first').click();
    }
});
```

I have debugged the code.  When the return button is pressed, the click event is actually triggered and the href variable is properly filled in BUT the page simply refreshes with a ? at the end of the URL rather than being redirected to the set href... (e.g. if I am in "index.php" and intend to go to "reports.php", instead of going there, the page is refreshed with url "index.php?"

Why would this be happening?

Answer (score 0):

i think what you meant to do is:

```
$(selector).trigger("click");
```

also:

window.location is an object. what you probably wanted to set is window.location.href

http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-window-location

Comment: so the problem is probably that the context of "this" differs.. try to create a jsfiddle and console.log($(this))

Comment: The context of this is correct because as I mentioned, the href variable is properly being filled with the correct URL.

Comment: then all that is left to go wrong is "window.location = href;"

Comment: are you sure that it isn't something else breaking your script?? it seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/KKJP6/3/

Comment: I created this jsfiddle and it is working for me in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/876ae/16/.  However I still can't understand why it's not working in my site...  Debugged my PHP to see if it was going to the right page and than redirecting back...but NO..the same page is being refreshed without ever going the the clicked URL...

Comment: No console errors...the last line executed is the actual redirect "window.location = href";  I think I am getting defeated and I'll end up creating and submitting a form on the fly hoping it works well.

Comment: Created the form on the fly..same problem..I'm out of ideas now

Comment: what does console.log(href) say if you comment out the last line executed (window.location....) and put the log statement before it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.. my mistake...

The native form submit was taking over the jquery code even though the form had no action and the there was no submit button anywhere.  All I had to do was to add onsubmit="return false;" in the form.